# Why does translated Gridview Linkbutton Text looses its value on async postback from update panel

Tags: asp.net, webforms, updatepanel

I have implemented a way to translate all may labels and linkbuttons, etc for an ASP.NET page from values of a database. The labels etc have a hardcoded Text-Value as fallback and on runtime the will be translated.

What I did is I basically wrote a`BasePage` which every page inherits from. I overwrote the `Page_Load` method looked for all required controls recursively and then changed the text. I learned that I have to use `Page_Load` since the Header `LinkButton` Text were not translated if I used `On_Init` `On_InitCompleted`.

However this works as expected as long as I did not click the `LinkButton` on a `GridView` column. Which triggers a postback (async) which runs through all my translation code. But lookin at the page, I see that the they flipped back to the hardcoded fallback text headers on the grid view (only gridview header). I am pretty sure this is something with the page life-cycle dance but cannot solve it.

I want to have all the translation logic in the BasePage and not subscribe to any GridviewEvents and change labels on binding etc.

It would be helpful to retain the translation of the gridview header through the async postback of an update panel.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experimented back and forth and decided to do the translation not in the beginning but in the end of the page life-cycle. 
So instead of `Page_Log` I do translation now in the `On_PreRenderCompleted` override.
Works now!